# chamada post não funciona, retorna erro 405

Tags: javascript, mvc, spring

tenho o seguinte javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            function calculaReducao(){
                var nd1 = document.getElementById("nrDentes1").value;
                var nd2 = document.getElementById("nrDentes2").value;
                $.post("calcularReducao?nd1=" + nd1 +"&nd2=" + nd2); 
            }        
</script>
```

a célula na tabela

```
<td><input type="button" onclick="calculaReducao();" value="Executar" /></td>
```

e o controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/calcularReducao", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView calcularReducao(double nd1, double nd2) throws IOException {

        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("/calculos.jsp");
        double resultado = nd2/nd1;
        mv.addObject("reducao", resultado);
        return mv;

    }
```

e com tudo isto, o clique do botão me retorna um erro 405, como se estivesse tentando fazer um get.

> Message Request method 'GET' not supported 
>   Description The method received in the request-line is known by the origin server but not supported by the target resource.

Answer (score 0):

Ele pode estar fazendo um `get` devido a passagem de argumentos `?nd1=`. Quando se faz post, o ideal é enviar dados no payload, e não na URL. Correção para o seu caso:

**Javascript**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function calculaReducao(){
        var nd1 = document.getElementById("nrDentes1").value;
        var nd2 = document.getElementById("nrDentes2").value;
        $.post("calcularReducao", { nd1: nd1, nd2: nd2 }); 
    }        
</script>
```

**Spring controller**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/calcularReducao", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView calcularReducao(@RequestParam double nd1, @RequestParam double nd2) throws IOException {

    ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("/calculos.jsp");
    double resultado = nd2/nd1;
    mv.addObject("reducao", resultado);
    return mv;
}
```

Comment: vou experimentar fazer como falou.onde posso dar feedback?

Comment: Aqui mesmo @RafaelPerracini, você diz se deu certo ou não.

Comment: não rolou, continua dando o mesmo problema...

Comment: Só para esclarecer, preciso usar o button pq faço várias chamadas para cálculos da mesma tela, então não uso submit...não sei se o button precisa estar dentro de um form, mas creio que não, uma vez que chama a função do javascript e o spring faz a ponte com o controller